# Spinner Not working in Safari, Internet Explorer and Edge

Tags: css, cross-browser, webkit, css-transitions

I added CSS Spinner For my web app. But that is working only in chrome. Safari and other browsers it is not working. Can anyone help me.

I added the fiddle here

[CSS Spinner](http://jsfiddle.net/iamparthi007/4f3s33hf/)

```
<div class="loading"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Checked on Chrome, Safari and Firefox in OSX.

Comment: I'm using windows safari @user3607282 . In Edge and Internet Explorer also not working. :(